# cType : string to date throwing InvalidCastException (ASP) (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am getting exception on following lines

```
InspectionDate = "07/15/2014"
If CType(InspectionDate, Date) > Date.Today Then

    'Here comes my logic etc
    'Here comes my logic etc
    'Here comes my logic etc

 End If
```

When i debugged i see Date.Today = #7/15/2014#

Can any one please help on this.

Thanks..

Comment: use `datetime.parse` instead

Comment: I just need to compare date not time too. Also can you please send me sample code for. Sorry, I am beginner in asp.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like this

```
Dim dt As Date = Date.ParseExact("07/15/2014","MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
IF dt > Date.Today Then
    'CODE HERE
END IF
```

Check the full documentation at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: I am getting "Undeclared Element" on                                                    ParseExact, CultureInfo and  InvariantCulture

Comment: Thanks, I had to import system.globalization

Comment: ohh.. sorry, i haven't mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
InspectionDate = "07/15/2014"
If DateTime.Parse(InspectionDate) > Date.Today Then

    'Here comes my logic etc
    'Here comes my logic etc
    'Here comes my logic etc

 End If
```

try like this

Comment: Now i am getting : `System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. at ... `

Comment: @Anjum that's because the given date format and your current culture date format are different otherwise it should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Before compare both dates use the TryParse method

```
 Dim dateValue as Date
 InspectionDate = "07/15/2014"
 If (Date.TryParse(InspectionDate, dateValue) > Date.Today Then

      'your code here

 End If
```

check the metod in the MSDN
[check the description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)